# PostgreSQL Quantity trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL:

```
Articles(id_article, price, name, section)
```

and

```
Section(id_section, quantity)
```

section is a foreign key in "Articles". I need a **trigger** that updates the quantity field from "Section" (for every tupla) when a new row in "Article" is inserted, updated(section change) or deleted.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your change of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case what specifically have you already tried, Also need sample data as text - **no images** and the expected results of that data.

Answer (score 2):

First read the official documentation of Postgres for your requirement [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Here is your trigger procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "fn_trig_section"()
      RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
     
    begin
            IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
                update section set quantity=quantity-1 where id_section=old.section;
                            return old;
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                update section set quantity=coalesce(quantity,0)+1 where id_section=new.section;
                            update section set quantity=quantity-1 where id_section=old.section;
                return new;
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                update section set quantity=coalesce(quantity,0)+1 where id_section=new.section;
                return new;
            END IF;
                    
    return NULL;
    end;
    
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100
```

and this is your trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_section
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON articles
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_trig_section();
```

Answer (score 2):

usefull ressource :

to create functions on postgresql : [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

to create trigger on postgresql : [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

Create function first :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_quantity_section() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER AS $$
BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            update Section set Section.quantity=Section.quantity-1 where Section.id_section=old.section;
            return old;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            update Section set Section.quantity=coalesce(Section.quantity,0)+1 where Section.id_section=new.section;
            update Section set Section.quantity=Section.quantity-1 where Section.id_section=old.section;
            return new;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            update Section set Section.quantity=coalesce(Section.quantity,0)+1 where Section.id_section=new.section;
            return new;
        END IF;
END;
$$;
```

then create your Trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_activity
     AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE 
     ON articles
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_quantity_section();
```